# Why me store procedure just return the result of the first IF?

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, db2

I'm using this code in SQL

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (
    IN in_School_ID INTEGER, in_Leader_Score INTEGER) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
    SET "Leaders_Score" = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    IF 'in_Leaders_Score' >=  '80' THEN 
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Very_Strong'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF 'in_Leaders_Score' >= '60' and 'in_Leaders_Score' <= '79'  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Strong'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF 'in_Leaders_Score' >=  '40' and 'in_Leaders_Score' <=  '59'  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Average'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF 'in_Leaders_Score' >=  '20' and 'in_Leaders_Score' <=  '39'  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Weak'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSE
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Very Weak'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
        END IF;
  END 
  @
```

But when a called the procedure and put any value in the second parameter, the row updated just return the string "Very_Strong" in the Leaders Icon column, can some give me a hint?

I already try to make the comparison this mode =>80 put i got this error:

Status:
Failed
Error message
Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.26.14

And I tried to put the 'in_Leaders_Score' with single quotes and I doesn't get error, but the code doesn't make the correct comparisons, and if I put this variable in double or without quotes i got this error:
Error message:
"LEADERS_SCORE" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: Your if statements are comparing literal strings, not variables to numbers.

Comment: Please tag your question with DBMS you are using. However, in_Leader_Score is defined as an integer but in your code you are treating it as a string - so your comparison code is not going to work in the way you want. >= 80 and >= '80' are not the same

Comment: When I tried to do the comparison with this way: >=80, when I try to call the function I receive this error: Status: 
Failed
Error message
Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: I guys and girl was a attention error, my variable was typed wrong, I delcared the variable as in_Leader_Score, and in the IF-ELSE statement I was putting in_Leaders_Score, so correcting this I remove all quotes in the IF-ELSE comparison, and the code worked fine! Tks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change column lengh by alter column data type as below

```
ALTER TABLE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
ALTER COLUM LEADERS_ICON SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct code now:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (
    IN in_School_ID  INTEGER, IN in_Leader_Score INTEGER) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
    SET "Leaders_Score" = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    IF in_Leader_Score >=  80 THEN 
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Very_Strong'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score>= 60 and in_Leader_Score <= 79  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Strong'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  40 and in_Leader_Score <= 59  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Average'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  20 and in_Leader_Score <= 39  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Weak'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
    ELSE
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET "Leaders_Icon" = 'Very Weak'
        WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
        END IF;
  END 
  @
```

**Tks for the insigths people**

Answer (score 0):

I'd not suggest you doing such things in future.
The whole logic may be implemented using just a single statement, which is much more readable.

```
UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
SET 
   "Leaders_Score" = in_Leader_Score
,  "Leaders_Icon" = 
   CASE 
     WHEN in_Leader_Score >= 80                            
       THEN 'Very_Strong'
     WHEN in_Leader_Score >= 60 and in_Leader_Score <= 79  
       THEN 'Strong'
     WHEN in_Leader_Score >= 40 and in_Leader_Score <= 59  
       THEN 'Average'
     WHEN in_Leader_Score >= 20 and in_Leader_Score <= 39  
       THEN 'Weak'
     ELSE 'Very Weak'
   END
WHERE "School_ID" = in_School_ID;
```

Comment: Tks for the advice Mark, in the next problems I'll try to make more clearly codes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using on IBM's db2:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE (
    IN in_School_ID  INTEGER, IN in_Leader_Score INTEGER) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
MODIFIES SQL DATA
  BEGIN
    UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
    SET Leaders_Score = in_Leader_Score
    WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    IF in_Leader_Score >=  80 THEN 
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very_Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score>= 60 and in_Leader_Score <= 79  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Strong'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  40 and in_Leader_Score <= 59  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Average'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSEIF in_Leader_Score >=  20 and in_Leader_Score <= 39  THEN
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    ELSE
        UPDATE "CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS"
        SET Leaders_Icon = 'Very Weak'
        WHERE School_ID = in_School_ID;
    END IF;
  END 
  @
```

This ran successfully. But my problem is when I try to call the procedure with this code:

```
CALL UPDATE_LEADERS_SCORE(610038, 50);
```

I get this error:

```
Status:
Failed
Error message
Value "Average" is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.31.10
Learn more about this error
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That because the data type is `VARCHAR(4)` for **LEADERS_ICON**, update
the data type by using the code below. It will solve your problem.

```
ALTER TABLE CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
ALTER COLUMN Leaders_Icon SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20);
```